# How do I add an external link in a module?

Tags: navigation

I'm attempting develop a module in drupal-8 that provides a link to an external password reset system. Specifically on the login page I'd like a *reset my password* link that points to a link such as https://reset.my.password/

I've tried adding my module.links.task.yml file. What else do I have to create to add an external link?

Comment: links.task.yml files are for defining [local tasks](https://drupalize.me/tutorial/links-overview-developers?p=2766).  It is not clear if that is the kind of link you are looking to achieve?  Where do you want the link to be displayed?  To whom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be very little information on this matter, maybe it's not that common to try to achieve something like this, but I stumbled across this thread while searching for a solution and I'd like to add my thoughts.

The comments stating that `links.task.yml` is for local tasks is right, but when it comes to external links, it's not that simple. As far as I know, you need routing to add links that way, and routing is for internal links, right?

So in the end I did it this way in Drupal 9:

```
  function my_module_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name) {    
    $data['tabs'][0]['node.extra_tab'] = array(
      '#theme' => 'menu_local_task',
      '#link' => array(
        'title' => t('Extra tab'),
        'url' => Url::fromUri('https://theurl.com', array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank'))),
        'localized_options' => array(
          'attributes' => array(
            'title' => t('Extra tab'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can also add something like `if ($route_name == 'entity.node.canonical')` to narrow it down and also `if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node') == 'my_content_type')` in case you want this to work only on certain content type(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement [`hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.2.x).

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_local_tasks_alter().
 */
function mymodule_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name, RefinableCacheableDependencyInterface &$cacheability) {
  foreach ($data['tabs'] as &$tab){
    $tab['routing_name']['#link']['url'] = Url::fromUri('https://reset.my.password/');
  }
}
```

Comment: See the comment on the question.